# Passing an array by reference to thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, templates, c++11, reference

I have an array that needs to be passed to multiple threads to be worked on. The array size is know at compile time.
Here is a working reduction to the essentials where the function is called directly, not via a thread:

```
#include <thread>

template <class TYPE>
void function(TYPE& data, std::size_t row, std::size_t column){
    data[row-1][column-1]=2;
}

int main(){
    const int column(5),row(2);
    std::array<std::array<int, column>, row> arr;
    function(arr, row, column);
    return data[row-1][column-1];
}
```

The code returns 2, as expected.
If I call the function via

```
    std::thread worker(function<std::array<std::array<int,column>,row>>, arr, row, column);
```

I get the following compiler error:

```
g++ Testo.cpp -o Testo -std=c++11 -lpthread
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/thread:39:0,
                 from Testo.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/functional: In instantiation of ‘struct std::_Bind_simple<void (*(std::array<std::array<int, 5ul>, 4ul>, int, int))(std::array<std::array<int, 5ul>, 4ul>&, long unsigned int, long unsigned int)>’:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/thread:137:47:   required from ‘std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = void (&)(std::array<std::array<int, 5ul>, 4ul>&, long unsigned int, long unsigned int); _Args = {std::array<std::array<int, 5ul>, 4ul>&, const int&, const int&}]’
Testo.cpp:13:82:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.8/functional:1697:61: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘class std::result_of<void (*(std::array<std::array<int, 5ul>, 4ul>, int, int))(std::array<std::array<int, 5ul>, 4ul>&, long unsigned int, long unsigned int)>’
       typedef typename result_of<_Callable(_Args...)>::type result_type;
                                                             ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/functional:1727:9: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘class std::result_of<void (*(std::array<std::array<int, 5ul>, 4ul>, int, int))(std::array<std::array<int, 5ul>, 4ul>&, long unsigned int, long unsigned int)>’
         _M_invoke(_Index_tuple<_Indices...>)
         ^
```

I can change my template to

```
template <class TYPE>
void function(TYPE data, std::size_t row, std::size_t column){
    data[row-1][column-1]=2;
}
```

and the compiler no longer complains, but main then returns 0 as the array is no longer passed by reference.
What is the appropriate first argument for the thread to call the correct template to pass the array by reference, as is working when calling the function directly?

Comment: `arr` is declared after you use it in `function`, so how is that supposed to work?

Comment: Your first code snippet [fails to compile](https://ideone.com/mTZK4i) since `arr` is defined after the function call.

Comment: Apologies, pasted that line in afterwards. Thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to pass  by reference `std::ref(arr)`

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick! 
Will mark as answered once the minimum of 7 minutes have passed.

Answer (score 7):

Your function expects a reference to the array but `std::thread` stores decayed copies of the bound arguments. Array-to-pointer decay results in a prvalue of pointer type. To fix, pass `arr` through a `std::reference_wrapper` to preserve the type:

```
std::thread worker(..., std::ref(arr), row, column);
```

You might also want to use a lambda so you won't have to explicitly pass the template arguments:

```
std::thread worker([&arr]{ return function(arr, row, column); });
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. The real function is only called twice in the code and has north of 20 arguments, so in this specific case, using a lambda would not reduce maintenance. But I'll definitely employ this in future applications.

Comment: If you're going to use a lambda, you may as well capture the arguments in the lambda instead of passing them through the thread constructor. It's both simpler and avoids problems like that of the OP: `std::thread worker([&arr]{ return function(arr, row, column); });`. (Note that `row` and `column` need not be captured: they are constants to which lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is immediately applied, and hence are not ODR-used by the lambda.)