# c++11 multithread, passing by reference

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, reference

```cc
void _function_(std::vector<long long>& results){

    results.push_back(10);
    return ;
}


int main(){

    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    std::vector<std::vector<long long>> results_array;
    for(int i=1;i<=N;i++){
    results_array[i]=std::vector<long long>();
    threads.push_back(std::thread(&_function_,results_array[i]));
    }

    for(auto& th : threads){
    th.join();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the c++ code. I want to use a `std::vector<long long>` to keep the result for each thread. So I initialize a 
`std::vector<std::vecotor<long long>>` for each thread. However, when passing the `results_array[i]`, I got the following errors:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/thread:39:0,
                 from multi-thread.cc:3:
/usr/include/c++/5/functional: In instantiation of ‘struct std::_Bind_simple<void (*(std::vector<long long int>))(std::vector<long long int>&)>’:
/usr/include/c++/5/thread:137:59:   required from ‘std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = void (*)(std::vector<long long int>&); _Args = {std::vector<long long int, std::allocator<long long int> >&}]’
multi-thread.cc:21:60:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/5/functional:1505:61: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘class std::result_of<void (*(std::vector<long long int>))(std::vector<long long int>&)>’
       typedef typename result_of<_Callable(_Args...)>::type result_type;
                                                             ^
/usr/include/c++/5/functional:1526:9: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘class std::result_of<void (*(std::vector<long long int>))(std::vector<long long int>&)>’
         _M_invoke(_Index_tuple<_Indices...>)
```

I also try `std::ref(results_array[i])`, but having sagmetation fault.

Can anyone help me on this issue? Thanks!

Comment: You're accessing objects that don't exist. If `results_array` is empty, you can't access any of the objects in it because there are no objects in it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing an array by reference to thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30169908/passing-an-array-by-reference-to-thread)

Comment: Simply initialize your `results_array` as `std::vector<std::vector<long long>> results_array(N);` and note that **indexes in C++ start from 0**.

Comment: or `results_array.push_back(std::vector<long long>());` to make inner vector exist at least.

Comment: Yes, that's .the problem. It works. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Here you have the code correct:

```
void _function_(std::vector<long long>& results){

    results.push_back(10);

    return ;

}
```

```
int main(){

    int N = 10;

    std::vector<std::thread> threads;

    std::vector<std::vector<long long>> results_array;

    for(int i=0;i<N;i++){

    results_array.push_back(std::vector<long long>());

    threads.push_back(std::thread(&_function_, std::ref(results_array[i])));

}

for(auto& th : threads){
th.join();
}
    return 0;
}
```

Your problem is at ths line:

```
threads.push_back(std::thread(&_function_, std::ref(results_array[i])));
```

you doesn't get the reference of results_array. 
Yo also have to correct as here

```
results_array.push_back(std::vector<long long>());
```

Comment: Note that `std::ref(results_array[i])` may result in a dangling reference depending on the behaviour of `results_array.push_back(..)`. Use the initialisation: `... results_array(N);` as has been suggested to create all the vectors before referring to individuals..

Comment: This clears some problems. But I fund the program will not terminate if the ``` results_array.push_back(std::vector<long long>()); ``` is called along with the ``` threads.push_back(std::thread(&_function_, std::ref(results_array[i])));``` in a same for loop. It works well if a use two for loop, the first for insert the vector and sescond for launching the thread